# How can my process/script avoid to be stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: algorithm, perl, loops, process, queue

I have a simple algorithm as follows omitting irrelevant things for clarity:

```
while( my $data = get_data() ) {  
   process($data);    
}  

sub get_data() {  
   return $dbh->execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE status = 'submitted'");  
}  

sub process {  
   my $data = shift;  
   foreach my $row (@$data) {  
      handle($row);  
   }  
}  

sub handle {  
   my $row = shift;  
   # process logic here  
   $dbh->execute("UPDATE TABLE SET status='done'" WHERE id = $row->id");   
}
```

Now the problem is that there is a bug that leads to an infinite loop. If during the handling and the core processing logic there is a failure and the code does not manage to update to status done then in the next loop it will retry the records over and over.
Adding a new status I think just moves the same problem elsewhere so I think that there is some kind of flaw in my logic.
Is there a way for a process to "understand" that it is stuck in a loop and does not progress? Or to rephrase as per @amit: Is there a way to avoid the infinite loop?
I could only come up with the following:
1) When I do the `get_data()` I add the rows to an in memory array so in the next loop I would do `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE status = 'submitted' WHERE id NOT IN (@array)`
This would work but for a large number of records e.g. 50000 it seems impractical to place them in an IN.
2) Try to see how many records where updated. If the sizeof($data) != number of updated records it could mean a stuck in the process.

Neither of these approaches seem nice to me. Can anyone please help me figure this out?

Comment: It cannot be done for a general case algorithm, this is the Halting Problem. (It does not seem to be the case here from quick look, just a comment - not an answer). Basically what I am saying - your question should be "How to avoid the infinite loop?" and not "How to detect it?"

Comment: @amit:I updated the title and the main question.

Comment: Adding a third state (submitted / error / done) is the way to go. If you think the error condition will clear itself up, you can always process the records in the error state from time to time.

Comment: @ikegami:Yes I mentioned that adding a third state i.e. error would move the same problem else where as the error should be eventually be processed as well as the cause of the error could have been fixed and the process will be retried

Comment: Exactly. It does everything you need.

Comment: @ikegami:Wait, won't I end up again in a loop for error?

Comment: It would be pretty dumb to create a job that continually retries error records. I suggested you only perform that job from time to time.

Comment: Do the records have sequence numbers in them? Approximately how many records do you expect to process per day?

Comment: @ikegami:That is a valid point.

Comment: @user3386109:Around 50.000 per day. What is the sequence number?If you mean like primary key yes

Comment: Two means come to mind: A cron job and/or a process initiated manually by whoever reviews the errors.

Comment: A sequence number is an incrementing numeric primary key. My suggestion is to only process records where the sequence number is greater than some minimum value.  Update the minimum after each batch of records is processed.  Records in the 'submitted' state where the sequence number is less than the minimum are the problem records that need to be reviewed manually.

Comment: @user3386109:That is a good idea except of the following:1)It needs to sort the result set e.g. via ORDER BY which makes it slower 2) The "gaps" between the last if of the previous run due to failures would be missed

Comment: @ikegami:Well this code runs in a cron job. So you are saying to split it into 2 cronjobs?

Comment: If you have two automated jobs that run periodically at different frequencies, a single cron job doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you use cron to process jobs periodically, why is there a loop? `process(get_data());`

Comment: Why not wrap everything in a transaction? If there's an error (in DBI *or* in the processing logic), rollback and retry a fixed number of times; otherwise, commit. If a transaction fails too many times, log it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:Because it would lock the table for the duration of the processing which is not small

Comment: But you're processing one row at a time; if you handle each row in its own transaction, you would only lock that particular row, and with the default transaction isolation level in InnoDB (which I assume you're using based on some of your previous questions), you would only be preventing other writes to that row during that time, not reads.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:That is correct, but when I rollback the status will be 'submitted' and I will still have the infinite loop;

Comment: Why would you have an infinite loop if you only retry failed transactions a fixed number of times as I suggested in my first comment? Perhaps I'm missing something...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:You mean `If a transaction fails too many times, log it`? So count the rollbacks?

Comment: Something like *(untested)*: `my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $pass, { RaiseError => 1 }); my ($success, $retries) = (0, 0); while (! $success && $retries < 3) { eval { dostuff(); $dbh->commit; $success = 1; }; if ($@) { $dbh->rollback; $retries++; } } $logger->warn("Transaction failed") unless $success;`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:+1.This is a nice idea and I will try to see if I can apply it in this part of the code.The problem is that the processing logic does quite a lot of processing and also interacts with a second database and additionally some of the processing is ok if it fails. So it is not like all the processing flow is one atomic unit

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to utilize an in-memory array (which I don't blame you for), are you able to modify your existing table or create another one?  If so, you could move successful updated records to the new table, even if it's only 2 columns, and then:

```
sub get_data() {  
   return $dbh->execute("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM NEW_TABLE)");  
}
```

It's difficult when dealing with this many records to maintain an in memory hash/array, especially if your application crashes for some reason.  At least this way you are making progress.

I don't see a different way in the programming logic to handle this.

Comment: Now that I think about it, add another value to the status column like 'processing'.  That way, you only search for 'submitted', and once you pick it up for process handling, update the status to 'processing' before working the rest of the logic where it can fail.  Then you can go back to check status = 'processing' for error records.  You might also consider logging to a file with the error message of why that record fails.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you show won't compile because of this line

```
$dbh->execute("UPDATE TABLE SET status='done'" WHERE id = $row->id");
```

which has too many double-quote characters to balance.

I think you are confusing yourself with so many subroutines to perform a simple task. I believe this short program does the same thing, and I think it is more readable.

Note that it is best practice to `prepare` each statement and to use placeholders in the prepared SQL string so that a subsequent `execute` can pass the actual data.

I haven't been able to test this code, as it would take a while to set up a sample database; but I have checked that it compiles.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dsn', 'username', 'password');

my $select   = $dbh->prepare(q{SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE status = 'submitted'});
my $set_done = $dbh->prepare(q{UPDATE TABLE SET status = 'done' WHERE id = ?});

$select->execute;

while (my $row = $select->fetchrow_hashref) {  
  $set_done->execute($row->{id});
}
```

Once you get this running there is a couple of problems that occur to me

- If all you want from `TABLE` is `id` then you shouldn't be using `SELECT *`
- You could write just `UPDATE TABLE SET status = 'done' WHERE status = 'submitted'`

But maybe your real situation is more complex? Please let us know so that we can help you better.

Comment: 1) I already said that the syntax is "short" 2) This is loop is not relevant to mine since there is a lot of processing between the while and the `$set_done->execute($row->{id});` which you skip here. I don't just do select/update 3)I know about the prepare etc.I write in perl but I made the code Perl-like for simplicity of the post and  people who don't know perl can understand my post

Comment: `If all you want from TABLE is id then you shouldn't be using SELECT * ` The rest of `*` I use them during processing (see the comment in handle sub) I have written the outline of the algorithm but you seem to focus in syntax details and optimizations. Now I am wondering if I should add more to the OP

Comment: @Jim: Erm, do you expect me to apologise? Where did you say that *'the syntax is "short"'*? This is a nasty response to someone who tried to help you, and you are blaming it on *me* that I didn't understand the full picture? You have a history of this Jim; please stop it. I have had to mark your question down as being too unclear, and your comments as *"rude or offensive"*. I will not take the rap for your poor description of the problem

Comment: I did not expect you to apologise. You are right on the syntax part. I wrote "omitting irrelevant things" which is not the same. I did not mean to be rude but I am not a native speaker.If I insulted you now or in the past as it seems I apologize. It was not my intention. It was more of "thinking out loud" sentences and wondering `if I should add more to the OP`

Comment: @Jim: I am sorry, but I don't believe that, whatever language is native to you, you didn't understand that it is rude to make a list of why an answer is *wrong*. You may get someone else to help you but you have lost this man

Comment: I am not sure why it is wrong (or rude) to argue that an answer might not be relevant to an OP in general. But I understand your point of view

Comment: I 'll be more careful next time